# How to create a simple Web Map with ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-online-webmap

Following the instructions on this page [Working with users, groups, and items—ArcGIS REST API: Users, groups, and content | ArcGIS for Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/working-with-users-groups-and-items.htm) and the [Add Item](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/add-item.htm) documentation I was able build a POST request in POSTMAN to add a new item to the user.

After getting the token, when I try the POST request to add the web map I get this error

```
{"error":{"code":403,"messageCode":"GWM_0003","message":"You do not have permissions to access this resource or perform this operation.","details":[]}}
```

[image: POSTMAN Request]

This is the JSON that contain some simple Web Map data,

```
{
    "operationalLayers": [],
    "baseMap": {
        "baseMapLayers": [
            {
                "id": "defaultBasemap",
                "layerType": "ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
                "url": "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer",
                "visibility": true,
                "opacity": 1,
                "title": "Topographic"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Topographic"
    },
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "authoringApp": "WebMapViewer",
    "authoringAppVersion": "5.4",
    "version": "2.11"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using the wrong access token.

I was using the access token I had for the app I was testing instead of the user's access token that I had to get with oauth2.

I'm leaving this here for future newbies.